# Solution to challenge of making a list

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

This is the answer to this challenge:

> ## Description
>
> Thanks for that list you made me, my thoughts are way more organised!
> I've got a few problems though that I thought you might be able to
> help with? Sometimes I put the wrong information in a list item. Maybe
> to prevent this I'd be able to modify/update the list item? That's not
> the only problem though, when there are 50+ items it gets kind of hard
> to work my way through. Do you think you could maybe add the ability
> to categorise my items? Obviously, if I have that, I'd also like to be
> able to view by category! Oh and finally, a few of you were really
> great and did this last time but is there a way you can somehow make
> my list retain state so that I don't have to re-type it everytime I
> turn my computer on again? The newest To-do list should be capable of
> the following functionality: Modifying an existing list item Be able
> to give a list item a category. The list item should be able to take
> an arbitrary amount of categorys View by category - All list items
> should be able to be sorted and output by category to make it easier
> to wade through submissions Retain state Thanks!
>
> ### Formal Inputs & Outputs
>
> #### Output description
>
> Any output that is created should be user-friendly. When I'm viewing
> my to-do list, I should be able to easily discern one list item from
> another. Examples
>
> (don't take this too literally, do it how you would like to do it)
> Categorisation
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> addItem('Go to work','Programming'); //Item belongs to the Programming     Category
> addItem('Create Sine Waves in C', 'Music', 'Programming); //Belongs to 2  categories, 'Programming' and 'Music');
> ```
>
> #### Category Output
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> viewList('programming');
> viewList('music');
> viewList('music', 'programming');
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
>  ----PROGRAMMING----
>   - A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel
>   - The Scheme Programming Language
>   - Memory in C
>   - Haskell's School of Music
>   - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code
>  
>  ----MUSIC----
> - Modes in Folk Music
> - The use of the Melodic Minor Scale
> - Haskell's School of Music
> - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code
>
> ----MUSIC & PROGRAMMING----
> - Haskell's School of Music
> - Algorithmic Symphonies from one line of code
> ```
>
> #### Modifying an item
>
> ```
> updateItem('Create Sine Waves in C', 'Create Sine Waves in Python');
> //The item has now changed from 'Create Sine Waves in C' to 'Create Sine Waves in Python'. This should be reflected in the
> ```
>
> viewList function/method you have created.

And my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class Category
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> list;
public:
    Category(const std::string& _name) : name(_name){ }

    void addItemToCategory(const std::string& item) { list.push_back(item); }

    void doneItemInCategory(const std::string& item) 
    { 
        for (auto it = list.cbegin(); it != list.cend(); ++it) {
            if (*it == item)
                list.erase(it);
        }
    }

    void updateItem(const std::string& oldItem, const std::string& newItem){
        for (auto it = list.cbegin(); it != list.cend(); ++it) {
            if (*it == oldItem){
                list.erase(it);
                list.push_back(newItem);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void displayCategory() const
    {
        for (const auto& item : list) 
            std::cout << "- " << item << "\n";
    }

    std::vector<std::string> const &getList() const { return list; }

    std::string const &getName() const { return name; }
};

class ShowCopies
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> existing;
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string &in)
    {
        return existing.insert(in).second;
    }
};

class ToDoList
{
    std::vector<Category> categories;
public:
    ToDoList() = default;

    template<typename... Args>
    void addItem(const std::string& item, Args&&... categorie){
        std::vector<std::string> _categories{ categorie... };
        for (auto category : _categories){
            if (!categories.size()){
                Category newCategory(category);
                newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);
                categories.push_back(newCategory);
            }
            else{
                const auto SIZE = categories.size();
                for (auto i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
                    if (categories[i].getName() == category){
                        categories[i].addItemToCategory(item);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        auto isInList = false;
                        for (const auto& _category : categories)
                            if (_category.getName() == category) 
                                isInList = true;
                        if (isInList) 
                            continue;
                        Category newCategory(category);
                        newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);
                        categories.push_back(newCategory);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void done(const std::string& item, const std::string& category){
        for (auto& cate : categories){
            if (cate.getName() == category){
                cate.doneItemInCategory(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void updateItem(const std::string& oldItem, const std::string& newItem){
        for (auto& category : categories) {
            category.updateItem(oldItem, newItem);
            break;
        }
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void viewList(Args&&... arguments) const{
        std::vector < std::string > hola{ arguments... };
        if (!hola.size() || hola.size()==1){
            for (const auto& category_ : categories){
                std::cout << category_.getName() << ": \n";
                category_.displayCategory();
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }
        else{
            for (int i = 0; i < hola.size(); ++i){
                std::cout << hola[i];
                if (i != hola.size() - 1) std::cout << " & ";
                else std::cout << ": \n";
            }
            std::vector<std::string> inCommon;
            for (const auto& category : categories){
                for (const auto& cate : hola){
                    if (category.getName() == cate){
                        for (const auto& item : category.getList()){
                            inCommon.push_back(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            std::vector<std::string> intermediate;
            std::remove_copy_if(inCommon.begin(), inCommon.end(), std::back_inserter(intermediate), ShowCopies());
            if (intermediate.size() && intermediate.size() != 1) {
                std::sort(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end());
                const auto remove = std::unique(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end());
                intermediate.erase(remove);
            }
            for (const auto& item : intermediate) std::cout << "- " << item << "\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ToDoList list;

    list.addItem("Geometry", "Homework");
    list.addItem("Mathematics", "Homework");
    list.viewList();

    list.updateItem("Mathematics", "Study programming");

    list.viewList("Homework");

    list.addItem("Wash my teeth", "Hygiene","Homework");

    list.viewList("Hygiene", "Homework");
    list.viewList();
}
```

Final code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>

class Item {
    std::string data;
public:
    Item() = default;
    Item(std::string dat) : data(dat) {}
    std::string getData() const {
        return data;
    }
};

class Category
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> list;
public:
    Category() = default;
    Category(const std::string& _name) : name(_name){ }

    void addItemToCategory(const std::string& nitem) 
    { 
        std::shared_ptr<Item> item(new Item(nitem));
        list.push_back(item); 
    }

    void remove(const std::string& item) 
    { 
        std::shared_ptr<Item> asditem(new Item(item));
        list.erase((std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [item](std::shared_ptr<Item> it) {return it->getData() == item; })));
    }

    void updateItem(const std::string& oldItem, const std::string& newItem){
        list.erase(std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [oldItem](std::shared_ptr<Item> it) {return it->getData() == oldItem; }));
        std::shared_ptr<Item> item(new Item(newItem));
        list.push_back(item);
    }

    void displayCategory() const
    {
        for (const auto& item : list) 
            std::cout << "- " << item->getData() << "\n";
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> const &getList() const { return list; }
};

class ShowCopies
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> existing;
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string &in)
    {
        return existing.insert(in).second;
    }
};

class ToDoList
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Category> categories;
public:
    ToDoList() = default;

    template<typename... Args>
    void addItem(const std::string& item, Args&&... categorie) {
        std::vector<std::string> _categories{ categorie... };
        for (auto category : _categories) {
            if (!categories.size()) {
                Category newCategory(category);
                newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);
                categories[category] = newCategory;
            }
            else {
                //If a category was found add the item to that category
                if (categories.find(category) != categories.end()) {
                    categories[category].addItemToCategory(item);
                }
                //otherwise create a category with that item on it
                else{
                    Category newCategory(category);
                    newCategory.addItemToCategory(item);
                    categories[category] = newCategory;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void done(const std::string& item, const std::string& category){
        auto it = std::find_if(categories.begin(), categories.end(), [category](const std::pair<std::string, Category>& C) { return C.first == category; });
        it->second.remove(item);
    }

    void updateItem(const std::string& oldItem, const std::string& newItem){
        for (auto& category : categories) {
            category.second.updateItem(oldItem, newItem);
            break;
        }
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void viewList(Args&&... arguments) const{
        std::vector < std::string > _categories{ arguments... };
        //If there are no parameters, print the whole list
        if (!_categories.size()){
            for (const auto& category_ : categories){
                std::cout << category_.first << ": \n";
                category_.second.displayCategory();
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (_categories.size() == 1) {
            std::cout << _categories[0] << "\n";
            categories.at(_categories[0]).displayCategory();
        }
        else{
            //cout category's names
            for (std::size_t i = 0, size = _categories.size(); i < size; ++i){
                std::cout << _categories[i];
                if (i != size - 1) std::cout << " & ";
                else std::cout << ": \n";
            }

            //Get every item that's in all the specified categories and put them in a vector
            std::vector<std::string> inCommon;
            for (const auto& cate : _categories) {
                auto it = categories.find(cate);
                if (it != categories.end()) {
                    for (const auto& item : it->second.getList()) {
                        inCommon.push_back(item->getData());
                    }
                }
            }

            //keep only the ones that are the same and then remove every copy so that at the end there's only one
            std::vector<std::string> intermediate;
            std::remove_copy_if(inCommon.begin(), inCommon.end(), std::back_inserter(intermediate), ShowCopies());
            if (!intermediate.size()){
                std::cout << "No items in common between these categories.";
            }
            else{
                while(std::adjacent_find(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end()) != intermediate.end() && intermediate.size() != 1 ){
                    std::sort(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end());
                    intermediate.erase(std::unique(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end()));
                }
                for (const auto& item : intermediate) std::cout << "- " << item << "\n";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    ToDoList list;

    list.addItem("Geometry", "Homework");
    list.addItem("Mathematics", "Homework");
    list.viewList();

    list.updateItem("Mathematics", "Study programming");

    list.viewList("Homework");

    list.addItem("Wash my teeth", "Hygiene","Homework");

    list.viewList("Hygiene", "Homework");
    list.viewList();

    list.addItem("Yea", "Yeeeeea");
    list.viewList();

    list.addItem("Jewellery", "spot", "not", "serious", "always", "as", "nueve");

    list.viewList("spot", "not", "serious", "always", "as", "nueve");
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overall performance isn't great. Consider using some hashing or trees. E.g., map categories' names to `Category` objects either by `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Also, it's a good idea to create a separate `Item` class for holding items and store pointers (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`) to them in category. In this case you'll have to find it only once during the update. In that case you can maintain circular references (item-to-category) via `std::weak_ptr`.

In your current implementation `find` (for finding a value) and `find_if` (for finding by predicate) from `<algorithm>` can be used instead of manual `for`-ing. It'll benefit your code a lot, as it's being used in most of your methods.

---

Minor things:

```
const auto SIZE = categories.size();
for (auto i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
```

maybe replaced with

```
for (auto i = 0, size = categories.size(); i < size; ++i) {
```

**upd:**

Okay, you've updated your code, but there are some issues left.

1. You can use same names for constructor's arguments and class field names.

   ```
   Item(std::string dat) : data(dat) {}
   ```

   Can be replaced with

   ```
   Item(std::string data) : data(data) {}
   ```
2. Return const references, not a copy.

   ```
   std::string getData() const {
   std::string const & getData() const {  // ok
   ```
3. Don't use `std::string` for items, you have `Item` class.
4. Use `make_shared`.

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<Item> item(new Item(nitem));
   std::shared_ptr<Item> item = std::make_shared<Item>(nitem);  // ok
   ```
5. You can use `set` here:

   ```
   //keep only the ones that are the same and then remove every copy so that at the end there's only one
   std::vector<std::string> intermediate;
   // ...
   ```

   So the code below will be way more simpler.
6. Implement `Item`'s operator operators such as `==` and `!=` with both `Item` and `std::string`. Then you can just use `std::find` without the explicit lambda.

---

More later.

Comment: Thank you for answering.                     

I've implement map, but I don't feel like I've done it right, since I rarely use the key, I most of the time iterate over categories and use its .first as its name. <- That made me remove getName() fucntion form class Category.


I don't know how smart pointers work, but I will look it up, just one question, how would the pointer that "pointers to them in category" works? Is it some kind of iterator?. Thank you.

Comment: No. My suggestion is to use something like ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>>‘.

Comment: @nightuser, about integrating `categories.size()` inside condition loop, I think this is better to assign `SIZE` before, this avoid calling `categories.size()` multiple times for nothing. But this requires you don't modify categories size during iterations.

Comment: @LeFlou: no, it will call size() only once.

Comment: What do you think [now](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5a8f07dc26e87ead30b7)?

Comment: @nightuser Finished it, [it looks like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0daf7088c8742d67bd93).

Comment: @Levon: please, add your code to the original question. It'll be easier to comment.

Comment: @nightuser Done

Comment: @nightuser code didnt compile since a typo error, re-edited and now it does